# What Types of Publications Are Common in Student Research Competitions at Academic Conferences?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, academic-life, poster

I am interested in understanding the specific types of publications that are typical for student research competitions at academic conferences.

What are the common formats (like extended abstracts, posters, etc.)? How do these differ from other tracks, such as full paper submissions? Also, what criteria are used to evaluate these student submissions?

Comment: Why does it matter what's typical? If you want to participate, what matters is how the specific conference you're considering does it.

Comment: The only 'student research competition' I'm familiar with is Best Poster awards which clearly are all about your poster (and your presentation of it to the various members of the selection jury).